# Html video remove black bottom shadow

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video, shadow

So, I have removed all the media controls in the video tag but I cannot remove  bottom black shadow. I want to remove the black shadow and show only play button.

How can I change video tag's the bottom shadow or remove it in the HTML?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any HTML and CSS code you have. Without it we cannot give you proper help. Thanks.

Comment: The code, screenshot, and browser will be helpful :)

Comment: Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/HzhnCpf.png

I want remove the yellow Section and view only the red Section ?